# How to refresh query table on Excel for Mac v16.31?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, power-query

I created a spreadsheet on Excel on Windows 10 with a query table connected to other tables in the same spreadsheet. However when this file is opened in Excel for Mac, refresh will not work. Nothing happens when I do right click -> refresh. When I do 'refresh all', I just get multiple prompts of "[The following data range failed to refresh:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzP9k.png), and then nothing happens again. Anyone knows why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: According to [Get & Transform (Power Query) in Excel for Mac](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel-Blog/Get-amp-Transform-Power-Query-in-Excel-for-Mac-Phase-1/ba-p/876840), it said that "please note that upon the first time you try to refresh your workbook queries, you may need to update the location of the data source so that it works on your Mac. Click the Data tab on the ribbon > Connections > select the desired connection > and click Change File Path button to update it." Please follow the tip to have a check.

Comment: I followed the path and I have the exact same dialog box as shown in the guide except that I dont have a 'change file path' button. Currently Im just running VMWare using windows version of Excel. Works fine.